# How do you edit Views within a dynamic UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

So basically I have a progress view, among others, within a UITableViewCell that is dynamic. How would I access the progress view (or any view) of a specific cell? I want to change the progress based on a value stored for that specific cell.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please be specific with what you want ? I don't understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a view controller (class) level property for progress and eventually implement a property observer so that you can refresh the view as soon as progress gets updated.

```
var progress: Double = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        updateProgressCell()
    }
}
```

Supposing that you know where (what's the row number - `progressCellRowNumber`) in your table is the progress view this is how you can implement the cell refreshing:

```
fund updateProgressCell() {
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: progressCellRowNumber, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I figured it out! I was getting an error saying I couldn't have a custom class for a dynamic prototype. I'm not sure what I changed but I was suddenly able to implement it the way I wanted.